# (Headless) Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS - rollback kernel?

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel

I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` today and it installed `linux-image 3.13.0-68`.

This seems to have broken something because the server will not boot.

However if I select a previous version such as `3.13.0-67` then the server boots fine.

How can I make it start with `3.13.0-67` by default?

And would I still have the option to upgrade the next time there is a kernel update?

Based on what I read one can edit `/etc/default/grub` apparently, but I am not wrapping my head around it.

Here are the contents of that file in case it helps:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the package with `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.13.0-68`. This won't affect your ability to use the next kernel verrson.

You can also configure the default Grub entry by changing the line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to equal the line number of the desired entry, where 0 is the first line. You then run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes. You may be confused by the fact that `/etc/default/grub/` is just a configuration file that helps generate the actual grub menu. You can see the actual Grub menu configuration under `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Comment: This actually may affect the upgrading, if they rely on the metapackage that automatically relies on the latest kernel; removing the latest kernel means they'll not get the later updates.

Comment: @ThomasW. wouldn't that only be the case if you explicitly remove the metapackage?

Comment: The metapackage depends on the packages it installs.  Remove a dependency, the thing requiring it gets removed.  That's how dpkg/apt work.